# Android- download body of html timetable

Tags: android, html, download, timetable

I'm writing an Android app for a Computing Project. I have a section of code that will download the html of a webpage and store it as a string- but it does not download the entire body of the html.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
package com.example.pete.computingproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;


public class async extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private Context mContext;

public async(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
@Override

protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    String content = null;
    URLConnection connection = null;


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        connection = new URL("https://stars.cirencester.ac.uk/index_bypass.php?view=tab_content/timetable&wk=6&stu_id=142669").openConnection();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        content = scanner.next();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(content);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("timetable1", content);
    editor.apply();
    return (content);




}


}
```

I want to download the source of the following page (right click, view source)
https://stars.cirencester.ac.uk/index_bypass.php?view=tab_content/timetable&wk=6&wk_num=&year=2015&stu_id=142669

However the code I'm using stops for some reason at line 40. I need all of it for my application to work. Any help would be appreciated!
If possible I would only like minor adjustments to my current code. However, if there is no way to do it without using completely different code, please do let me know. 
Thanks!

Comment: However long the code is, please include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend working with the dependency "OkHttp", instead of breaking your head on the sockets, The job done for you.

**Add dependecy:**
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'

**Learn more about how to use it**
Learn more from here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: I'm using android studio and I'm also very new to Android (if you hadn't noticed). Is this compatible in vanilla android or is this an external library? I'm cautious about using them as I haven't before.

Comment: It's java library, means it can run on any platform can run java (basiclly), I do belive it will work on vanilla too, haven't tried by myself. 
Anyway, its "imported" to the project, like "additional code", you just need to "import" the libraries and you can use the methods it supplies.
You can learn more here: http://square.github.io/okhttp/